# What should my function be a member of in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, function, user-interface

I'm making a simple GUI with Qt Creator.

I'm trying to make an 'openFile' function in the mainwindow.cpp file, but I don't know whether to make this function a member of the mainwindow itself, a separate static function, or a member of a widget.

This function is simple really, it just calls a QFileDialog, gets the path to a file, and opens it, like every open file command on the menu bar you've ever seen.

Now here's the major problem I am having.  I tried making this function a member of mainwindow so that I can access ui elements from within the function with `ui->QTableWidget` for instance, but I can't properly connect the signal to the slot if I do that. I get a whole slew of errors, because in order to do that I need a reference to the mainwindow since connect has the syntax `connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot)`

I then resorted to making the function separate on its own, but then it has no access to any of the ui elements.

How should I resolve this problem?

**EDIT**
Here is what I am doing in the constructor.

```
//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->actionOpen, &QAction::triggered, *parent, &MainWindow::openFile);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(16);
}
```

Here is the resulting error:

```
C:\workspace\audioPipe\audioPipe\mainwindow.cpp:76: error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect<void(__cdecl QAction::* )(bool),void(__cdecl MainWindow::* )(void)>(const QAction *,Func1,const MainWindow *,Func2,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'QWidget' to 'const MainWindow *'
with
[
    Func1=void (__cdecl QAction::* )(bool),
    Func2=void (__cdecl MainWindow::* )(void)
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: It probably should be a member of your mainwindow class.

Comment: "How should I resolve this problem?" Please post the smallest program that produces the errors that you are seeing along with the errors.

Comment: "but I can't properly connect the signal to the slot if I do that. I get a whole slew of errors" this is not expected.

Comment: Your connect() is very different from the form I have used 1000s of times that makes use of SIGNAL() SLOT() macros. I am not sure I can help with that.

Comment: Are you using Qt4 or Qt5? Either way you should be using `parent`, not `*parent`

Comment: This is Qt 5.0.  If I use `parent` instead of `*parent`, it says `cannot convert from QWidget * to const MainWindow`

Comment: @drescherjm: See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qt5-intro.html

Comment: Is MainWindow derrived from QWidget?

Comment: The default class definition that creator made for me is as so: `class MainWindow : public QMainWindow`

Comment: That makes sense. I can not use Qt5 yet because of library dependencies in most of my projects.

Comment: Uh, have you tried `connect(ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFile()));`?

Comment: So what does that mean? Because the class is derived from QMainWindow, I can't make openFile a member of mainwindow and connect it properly? How?

Comment: What happens when you use this instead of *parent in your connect?  QObject::connect(ui->actionOpen, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::openFile);

Comment: Taylor, yes the old syntax works! It's easier and makes more sense even. But just out of remaining curiosity, is there no way to do it with the new syntax though?

Comment: drescherjm, yes that also works.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @krb686: Even if the old connect-convention looks simpler, it has the disadvantage of not being compile-time checked.

Comment: By the way: the reason "parent" wasn't working is that the slot was `MainWindow::openFile` but the object you were trying to use was a QWidget. You can't call `MainWindow::openFile` on something that's not a MainWindow, or can't be converted to a MainWindow (hence the error message).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that as a third parameter to connect(), it expects a pointer to a MainWindow, i.e. a `const MainWindow *`. You however pass `*parent`, which is of type `QWidget`. Furthermore, `parent` is the wrong object anyway, since that is the parent of the MainWindow object, however you want to pass the MainWindow object itself - and that is `this`.

So something like the following should work:

```
    QObject::connect(ui->actionOpen, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::openFile);
```